# J2EE - implementing constantly running component/daemon

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, backgroundworker, daemon

I am designing a server application, that is supposed to crunch a lot of data continuously and present results on demand using web interface.

The operating scheme goes roughly like this:

1. An electronic sensor array constantly spills data into ramdisk through USB
2. A "flusher" application processes data as fast as it can and loads it into db (staging area)
3. Using triggers, db performs calculations on data and stores results in another schema (data area)
4. Client webapp can display processed data in graphs/reports etc. on demand

The solution would ideally look like this:

1. Database server - PostgreSQL
2. Have an administration web interface, that can monitor the flusher (i.e. records processed per hour or something like that) and if implemented as separate daemon, control it.
3. Flusher and Client applications written in Java, ideally using J2EE

Now the problem that keeps bugging me and I can't find the answer: How to go about writing the flusher component, i.e. a process that constantly runs in background in J2EE.

By scouring the web, basically three possibilities emerged:

a) Write the flusher as message driven bean and control it from master application using JMS. However: I don't like the idea of having a MDB running constantly, I'm not even sure that that's possible

b) Write the flusher as EJB and control it using Timer/Scheduling service. However: the events are not really timed, it just needs to run in infinite loop until told not to do so, just seems wrong usage of the technology.

c) Write the flusher as separate java application, run it as OS service (Linux or Windows) and control using startup scripts through ProcessBuilder invoked from EJB. To monitor it's status, use JMS. However: this just seems to me as overly complicated solution, platform dependent and maybe even unreliable and as EJB should not spawn/manage it's own threads, which ProcessBuilder basically does, it just seem wrong.

Basically, none of these look right to me and I cannot figure out, what would we the right solution in the Java/J2EE world.

Thank you
Thomas

Comment: It is perfectly ok to "[have] a MDB running constantly."  In fact, that's how they're supposed to work.  You deploy your MDB and then it processes messages as soon as they arrive.  That being said, I don't think MDBs are right in this situation.  You would need yet another process that wrapped your sensor data in a JMS message and then put it on a queue somewhere which seems like it would add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they're very helpful. To elaborate on the subject of MDBs, I get the principle behind them, but let's clear it in this case: What I meant by constantly running was the fact that I would send a message to the bean, which would invoke a method that itself would run in infinite loop, processing and flushing data. And that's what just seems wrong as the container would not be able to manage the bean properly (i presume), as executing of the method exits only either on stop-message sent from web interface for example, or on server shutdown.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  I agree, that would be a terrible design for a MDB app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the "Flusher" app as a stand alone Java process.  Perhaps use something like [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) to turn it into a service for your OS.  I'm not very familiar with the options for interfacing with a RAM disk via Java, but you're either going to end up with an InputStream which you can keep open for the life of the process and continually read from, or you're going to continually poll from inside a while loop.  It's perfectly ok to do something like the following:

```
private volotile boolean stopFlag;

...

while(!stopFlag) {
  processNextInput();
}
```

Then you would have some other mechanism in another thread that could set stopFlag to true when you wanted to terminate the process.

As for monitoring the flusher JMX seems like a good solution.  That's exactly what it was intended for.  You would create an MBean that would expose any kind of status or statistics you wanted and then other processes could connect to that MBean and query for that data.

The "Client" app would then be a simple servlet application which does reporting on your database and provides a pretty front end for the MBean from your flusher.  Alternatively you could just monitor the flusher using a JMX console and not even involve the client with that piece of the system.

I don't think EJBs really make sense for this system.  I'm somewhat biased against EJBs, so take my advice with a grain of salt, but to me I don't really see a need for them in this application.

Comment: Well, the flusher/JMX solution looks good (should've realised by myself), the only thing that I won't be able to do is to start stop the flusher daemon from the client/monitoring webapp (provided that it's components run in J2EE container environment), is that correct?

Comment: I've implemented something very similar, though using the Apache Daemon code: http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html . The JMX monitoring was quite straightforward, and let me graph performance statistics using Zenoss.

Comment: @Adrian: that's interesting suggestion worth looking into. Thank you for that.